# asp.net razor core insert multiple records on post

Tags: razor, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I trying to create an email log when an email is sent.

I have created a foreach loop to add the records to the database.

However, I can only get it to add one record when the `await _context.SaveChangesAsync();` is outside the loop.

If I put `await _context.SaveChangesAsync();` inside I get the following error.

> SqlException: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'EmailLog' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Code:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(IEnumerable<int> emailuser)
{
    //get login user
    var claimsIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)this.User.Identity;
    var claim = claimsIdentity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name);

    var TestAimItem = _context.AimItem.Where(x => emailuser.Contains(x.Id)).ToList();
    foreach (var item in TestAimItem.GroupBy(item => item.Email))
    {
        EmailMessage = await _context.EmailMessage.SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.Id == 2);
        string EmailAddress = (item.Key);
        var emailMessage1 = EmailMessage.MessageBody.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "<br/>");
        var linkHtml = "<a href=" + '"' + "https://" + EmailMessage.Link + '"' + ">here</a>";
        var emailMessage2 = emailMessage1.Replace("HPWDLINK", "click " + linkHtml);
        var emailMessage3 = emailMessage2.Replace("HPWDUSEREMAIL", EmailAddress);
        var emailMessage4 = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(emailMessage3);

        await _emailSender.SendEmailAsync(To, EmailMessage.MessageSubject, emailMessage4);
    }

    foreach (var item1 in TestAimItem)
    {

        EmailLog.EmailDate = DateTime.Now;
        EmailLog.MessageId = 2;
        EmailLog.SentTo = item1.Email;
        EmailLog.SentBy = claim.Value;

        //submit record
        _context.EmailLog.Add(EmailLog);
        //await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    }
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    return RedirectToPage("/UserReporting/EmailUsersAnnualReport");
}
```

Comment: You're trying to add the *same `EmailLog`* instance to the db multiple times, so the second time time around, it has an ID that was set by the previous call to `SaveChangesAsync` - hence, the error. When you do `SaveChangesAsync` outside of the loop, you just add *one instance* of `EmailLog` to the db, which works but is not what you want.

Comment: Thanks, Kirk...any thoughts on how to make it work? Can I refresh/update the ID or db instance?

Comment: Solution: 
                EmailLog = new EmailLog();
 Kirk thanks for the input it was helpful and got me the right path